# ORA-01704: string literal too long using long UTF-8 Character set

Tags: oracle, utf-8, plsql

I'm testing a recently converted a database to UTF-8. If I use long random UTF-8 characters to insert into a varchar2 field (4000 characters) I get:
[ORA-01704: string literal too long using long UTF-8 Character set]

If I cut the string down to about 3600 characters, it works. What gives? Is there a way to insert my 4000 characters?

Note that there are some pretty strange characters in the string.

Thanks.

Comment: A `varchar` column can never hold more than 4000 ***bytes*** whether or not you declared it with `char` semantics or `byte` semantics. This has changed with 12c where you can configure the database to allow for 32K.

Comment: Do you have any strings in your database that are actually 4,000 bytes? If not then it doesn't matter at the moment, does it? Your testing has failed, you now know why but you've no need for it anyway.

Comment: Lots and lots of 4000 character fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50977):

> Independently of the maximum length in characters, the length of VARCHAR2 data cannot exceed 4000 bytes.

So a field declared as `varchar2(4000 [char])` can hold 4000 single-byte characters, or a lower number of multi-byte characters. You can't get around that, at least until 12c when `varchar2` supports up to 32k.

If you do actually need to allow 4000 multi-byte characters in 11g or earlier you will need to create the column as a `CLOB`, which can hold gigabytes of data. (You might want to [read more on LOB storage](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_tables.htm#ADLOB45273) as well).

Comment: Thanks. 

Since going the CLOB or c12 route isn't possible, then my choice is Lemons or Limes (as I reach for the sugar bowl).

Comment: Or the tequila... As Ben mentioned, it's only going to be an issue if you have real values that are multi-byte and get that long; but then if you didn't you'd have a smaller field anyway I suppose.

Comment: But as @RickyD is migrating to a UTF-8 database the assumption is that there are a number of 4,000 character columns that are being re-created as 4,000 character (i.e. 16,000 byte) columns, but the data from the old database is still 4,000 bytes Alex. It only becomes an issue if there is actually a need to insert more than 4,000 _bytes_ into the database. At the moment, it doesn't seem like there is. It's worth seriously investigating as migrating all the code to use CLOBs will be horrible and have a massive imp7act on the application (hence you don't want to do it later either!).

Comment: @Ben - true; all existing data must have been (up to 4000) single-byte characters, and the fact it's now UTF-8 doesn't necessarily mean multi-byte characters will actually be used, since that's the default CS and the recommendation now. If the real data will still only be single-byte this is a non-issue, I agree. (So my 'but' is wrong...)

Answer (score 1):

> Better you Change the datatype of the column to clob

Answer (score 1):

A single UTF-8 character can be more than 1 byte long. Oracle has a limit of 4000 bytes. Therefore less then 4000 UTF-8 characters will fit into a 4000 char length column.